# Creating a virtual parallel for Windows 7 using C++

Tags: virtual, emulation, io-redirection, parallel-port, lpt

I am developing an application which would redirect i/o from parallel port of, say, **device A** to the parallel port of **device B**. The two devices are connected on ethernet (LAN, WAN, internet, etc.).

**Device A** has a physical parallel port attached to it but **device B** is a machine with no parallel port on it. This is what makes me emulate a parallel port on **device B** such that windows thinks that it has a parallel port and works in the very manner with it as it works with parallel ports on hardware e.g. it auto detects when a device gets attached to the parallel port so that a driver for that device can be installed.

If any piece of hardware gets attached to the parallel port on **device A** the i/o is redirected to the parallel port on **device B** and the Windows on **device B** thinks that some hardware got attached to **device B's** own parallel port i.e. Windows doesn't know where in the world the hardware actually got attached; Windows just got fooled into thinking that the hardware is attached directly to **device B**.

My question is about the emulation part. How do I write a parallel port emulator in C++ for Windows 7 such that I fool Windows into thinking that it has a real/hardware parallel port?

A related question can be how does windows detect the hardware and on going changes in it e.g. when some hardware gets connected to the parallel port of a computer.

The program flow would be as follows.

1. Read data from **device A's** parallel port.
2. Write that data to **device A's** socket which sends it over to **device B's** socket.
3. Read data from **device B's** socket.
4. Write that data to **device B's** parallel port which makes windows think that some hardware got connected to it.

**NB:** I am to emulate a parallel port only i.e. parallel to parallel redirection only. No use of other ports on **device B** is allowed. That is a requirement for this application.

The part I've done so far is that I have written a program in C++ which reads and writes data from and to the parallel port respectively.

Please also let me know if you know of a better approach of parallel port to parallel port redirection over ethernet (LAN, WAN, internet, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this question in my own search for LPT virtualization on windows.
I know this one is old and unfortunately I don't have an direct answer to the it either, but I thought I'll share what I've found so far that could help you getting started:

- Lakeview Research's [Parallel Port Central](http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm)
- Benryves.com, [Remapped IO.DLL](http://www.benryves.com/products/remappediodll)
- Downtown Doug Brown's [Sivava Willem EPROM programmer on Windows 7 64-bit](http://www.downtowndougbrown.com/2010/10/sivava-willem-eprom-programmer-on-windows-7-64-bit/)

Comment: Such a thing is so old nowadays that this project was closed at my company. Although I am the one who asked the question to begin with, I will never want to do something such as this ever in the future.